# How do I turn off CTRL + Left Click= Rightclick With Better Touch Tool?

Tags: keyboard, imac, bettertouchtool

Well, it's a simple question. How do I turn off CTRL + Left Click= Right-click With Better Touch Tool? I see that other people figured it out but I can't quite figure it out. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What did you do (instructions that you followed) that didn’t work for you?

Comment: I didn't actually do anything. I was trying to figure it out on my own. I also just got Karabiner if you could explain how that works. Thanks!

Comment: Had any solution on that?